Does a vector change under coordinate transformation?
Let say there is a point in the $xyz$ coordinate system, then I can draw a position vector from the origin and define $\mathbf r=x\mathbf{i}+y\mathbf{j}+z\mathbf{k}$. Now I rotate the coordinate about the $z$ axis by an angle $\phi$, and define a position vector to the same point $\mathbf{r'}=x'\mathbf{i'}+y'\mathbf{j'}+z'\mathbf{k'}$.
It is obvious that the magnitude remains the same and the components may change, but does the equality $\mathbf{r}=\mathbf{r'}$ hold? In other words, are the two vectors equal?

The vector as an abstract object is independent of its coordinate representation, however your equality does not hold because you have specified $\mathbf r$ and $\mathbf r^\prime$ to be inequivalent representations.

@paulina While the triple $(x,y,z)$ will not be equal to the triple $(x',y',z')$, that's just representation. When represented as a triple without the implied sum (i.e., $\vec r = x\vec i + y\vec j + z\vec k$) some information has been removed. After removing this information, what's left (the two triples, in this case) are incomparable. The two representations are the same vector.

@DavidHammen it seems that I missed the basis vectors were also transformed. In that case, yes, you are correct.

There are two equivalent points of view. Say your original vector is
$$
{\bf r} = x\, {\bf i} + y\, {\bf j} + z\, {\bf k}
$$
Passive transformations leave the vector unchanged, but change the basis vectors, so the equation is
$$
{\bf r} = x'\, {\bf i'} + y'\, {\bf j'} + z'\, {\bf k'}
$$
Active transformations leave the basis vectors unchanged, but act on the vector itself, so the new equation is
$$
{\bf r}' = x'\, {\bf i} +y'\,{\bf j} + z'\,{\bf k}
$$
In both cases, the components of the vector $(x,y,z)$ transforms to $(x',y',z')$.

Just want to comment that this is what I would have replied, but you managed to write this answer like 80% more succinctly than I would have! Well done.

Yes, $\mathbf r = \mathbf {r'}$. If you express $\mathbf{i,j,k}$ as linear combinations of $\mathbf{i',j','k'}$, multiply them by $x,y,z$ respectively, and collect multiples of $\mathbf{i',j',k'}$ together then you will get $x'\mathbf {i'} + y'\mathbf {j'} + z'\mathbf {k'}$.

Finally an answer that actually addresses the question. The two vectors are the same because the change in the components and the basis vectors upon a coordinate transformation nullify each other to give the original representation.

While your question is about rotations around the origin, if you allow more general coordinate transformations (namely shifting the origin), then for position vectors (and quantities derived from them like angular momentum) there is a more subtle transformation behaviour (which lead to cases where the you can't say that $\vec r$ and $\vec r'$ are the same objects, because they no longer live in the same space).
The problem is, that position vectors are not vectors in the same sense as, e.g., the magnetic or electric field, which are, in a way, attached to the point they are measured at, and just change their components according to the rotation of space (in more advanced terms they live in the tangential space of the manifold that models space and transform as vectors in that space).
So if we have a transformation where we rotate around the origin (with a rotation matrix $R$) and then translate it (by a displacement $\vec d$), the electric field transforms like:
$$ \vec E'(\vec r') =  R \vec E(\vec r) $$
A position vector $\vec r$ can not be understood that way, if we rotate around and then translate the origin as above it changes as:
$$ \vec r' = R \vec r + \vec d. $$
(This is a kind of abuse of notation, as we consider $\vec r$ to live in the coordinate space here.)
So position vectors are another kind of object, and on the level of abstract those belonging to different origins are only equal in so far, that we understand them as the coordinates of the same point in space.
(One way to connect such position vectors to the model of space as a manifold, is to see them as elements of the tangential space at the origin. This only works that way, because we work in "boring" Euclidean space, where we can identify the tangential space at the origin with the space itself.)

+1 -- This is really important, but one thing that's missing here is to note that the transformation the OP asks about is a pure rotation, hence doesn't shift the origin.

I just posted recently, but: this $\uparrow$. A point $p$ is not a vector, is a geometric object that lives in an affine space, which has an origin $O$. Given $O$, we can make a vector $\vec p = p - O$ and use $\vec p$. Just remember, it is different from $p$ geometrically, though they have the same components in different representations. See also: The First (and Second / Inverse / Reverse) Geodetic Problem. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesy), and also, the more general affine transformation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation

@Amit I thought m first paragraph made it clear enough that this is only relevant if you allow translations. I'll make this more explicit.

As written, $r=r^\prime$.  However, it is worth considering several details for nearby questions:

It is very useful to distinguish between a true "vector" and what is called a "coordinate vector," which is a tuple of values such as (x, y, z).
A passive transformation adjusts the basis but not the vector, which is what you describe.  In these situations, the vectors are the same, but they are described with different coordinate vectors.  Phrasing more strictly, vectors (true vectors) are not affected by changes of bases.

This detail can be mighty difficult if you're a programmer.  Decoupling the idea of a true vector from the 3 doubles describing it is quite difficult for our kind.


An active transformation would change the vector, such that $r\ne r^\prime$.  This would occur when you change from (x, y, z) to (x', y', z') without changing the bases correspondingly.  This sort of thing happens when you say something like "take this object.  Now rotate it 45 degrees counterclockwise."


Yes, the two vectors are the same because a vector is a geometrical object, which means it is independent of any specific coordinate system. We only use coordinate systems to represent a vector in a certain way that's convenient to us.
In your example, what you can do to convince yourself that it is indeed the same vector is to write it out explicitly in terms of its basis vectors:
$$ \vec{r} = x\hat{x}+y\hat{y}+z\hat{z} $$
Now, another way to write this same equation, is:
$$ \vec{r} = \begin{pmatrix} \hat{x} & \hat{y} & \hat{z} \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix} $$
The reason it can be useful in this context, is that it can help you see that when you transform to a different coordinate system what really happens is that the identity matrix in the middle "splits" into two: a matrix on the right that transforms the components, and a matrix on the left that transforms the basis vectors. The product of these two matrices is of course the identity (they must be the inverse of one another), for the equation to remain unchanged. Hence, establishing that the vector itself never changes regardless of its representation.
In the case of your example where we want to represent the same vector after  rotating the coordinate system around the $z$ axis by some fixed angle $\varphi$:
$$ \vec{r} = \begin{pmatrix} \hat{x} & \hat{y} & \hat{z} \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} \cos\varphi & -\sin\varphi & 0 \\ \sin\varphi & \cos\varphi & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} \cos\varphi & \sin\varphi & 0 \\ -\sin\varphi & \cos\varphi & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix} $$
If you do the multiplication to the right and to the left you'll find:
$$ \vec{r} = \begin{pmatrix} \cos\varphi\hat{x}+\sin\varphi\hat{y} & -\sin\varphi\hat{x}+\cos\varphi\hat{y} & \hat{z}\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x\cos\varphi +y\sin\varphi  \\ -x\sin\varphi+y\cos\varphi \\ z \end{pmatrix} $$
Now we can give new names to both the basis vectors and to the components, for example:
$$ \hat{x}' = \cos\varphi\hat{x}+\sin\varphi\hat{y} , \ \ \  \hat{y}' = -\sin\varphi\hat{x}+\cos\varphi\hat{y} \ \ \ , \hat{z}' = \hat{z}$$
and
$$ x' = x\cos\varphi +y\sin\varphi , \ \ \  y' =  -x\sin\varphi+y\cos\varphi , \ \ \ z' = z$$
So that the above equation for $\vec{r}$ can be rewritten in terms of the new, rotated coordinate system:
$$ \vec{r} = x'\hat{x}'+y'\hat{y}'+z'\hat{z}'$$
A lot of the confusion when dealing with coordinate transformations, is that we often only look at how the components change: $x\rightarrow x'$, $y\rightarrow y'$, etc. but forget that the basis vectors change as well. That's because the components are what we actually "plug in" when we do concrete computations.
Note also that this differs from what you wrote by the fact that there's no reason to put a prime on the $\vec{r}$ itself. Since the whole point is that $\vec{r}$ is the same object all throughout, we only need to put primes on things like transformed components and transformed basis vectors, to distinguish them from unprimed components and unprimed basis vectors. Overall however, the combination gives us the same geometrical object, $\vec{r}$.

Just as “a rose by any other name would smell as sweet”, a vector represented in two different coordinate systems are the same vector. In other words, $\vec r\,\text' = \vec r$.

It depends on exact coordinate transformation type taken.
Rotation about origin
Take as an example coordinate clockwise rotation by $\pi/2$,  as pictured here

Such transformation has coordinate mappings :
$$ \begin{cases} 
x'=-y\\
y'=x\\
\mathbf e_x'=-\mathbf e_y\\
\mathbf e_y'=\mathbf e_x
\end{cases} \tag 1$$
Using (1) definitions we can check new $\mathbf r'$ vector integrity :
$$
\begin {align}
\mathbf{r}'&=x'\mathbf{e_x}'+y'\mathbf{e_y}'\\
&=-y(\mathbf{-e_y})+x\mathbf{e_x}\\
&=x\mathbf{e_x}+y\mathbf{e_y}\\
&=\mathbf{r}
\end {align}
\tag 2$$
So by (2) we have shown that rotation about an origin does not changed our input $\mathbf r$ vector.
Origin translation
If you for example translate coordinate origin like here :

by performing origin vector mapping $$ \mathcal O~' = \mathcal O+\mathbf r \tag 3$$
then obviously $\mathbf {r'} \ne \mathbf {r}$, since now $\mathbf {r'}=\overrightarrow{0}$ (null vector).
Similarly it can be proven that origin any translation in the form $\mathcal O~' = \mathcal O+\mathbf k$, where $\mathbf k$ is arbitrary shift vector (except null vector),- changes either input vector $\mathbf r$ direction, magnitude or both.
